# RxJS HTTP-Client: response type for not JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I am not sure whats the problem here. I'd like to make a HTTP-request that does respond binary data (e.g. a file download) instead of JSON.

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from "@angular/common/http";
```

These lines are ok - but expect JSON.

```
let x = this.http.get <any> ("http://myhost", { responseType : 'json' });
let y = this.http.get <any> ("http://myhost");
```

But I need to define the response to be not JSON.

```
let z = this.http.get <any> ("http://myhost", { responseType : 'string' });
```

Here I get a problem with it. I tried 'blob' as well.
I always get a typescript-error at compile-time.

> Argument of type '{ responseType: "string"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
>     Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
>       Type '"string"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.

Comment: Have you tried `responseType: 'text'`? `text` rather than `string`? I don't think `string` is a valid response type.

Comment: Yes, text also gives this error.

Comment: Remove `<any>`, use blob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is a file, please use `blob`, but you need to remove the generic argument. Use:

```
his.http.get("http://myhost", { responseType : 'blob' });
```

The version that takes the generics will only work with JSON, as it is designed to parse the response

Comment: @user184994  
const options = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': this.sessionTokenForSuccessfullyLoggedUser,
                'Accept': contentType
            }),
            responseType: 'blob'
        };
        return this.http.get(urlPath, options)
error: Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"json"
same error but no success for me: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586